# JButton when clickedl leaves some border around text

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I am having one simple form i created using JFrame.

In which i used one small JButton in which i set text only "X", now the problem is that when i press that button **some border appears around the text which should not appear.**

So, how can i resolve it?

**How can i remove this border.I mean to say when the user clicks then also it should not show this border.**[image]

Here Try to look at the button at the corner with red background.

Comment: in your picture, i don't see any text in the buttons..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a keyboard focus indicator. If you want that never appear call `setFocusable(false)` for that button.